# How to record the video and make slow down with current playbackrate?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation

I can able to take the video from the temp url and save the video in the photo library.

How to make the video with ramp slow motion ? I know this can able to done by currentplayrate. I'm not sure how to apply it.

How to adjust the speed before saving it to the photo library?

Note : I used MPMoviePlayerViewController to play/trim and save the video.

Code for reference :

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    // 1 - Get media type
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    // 2 - Dismiss image picker
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    // Handle a movie capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        // 3 - Play the video
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
            initWithContentURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];

         theMovie.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackRate = 4.0f;

        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
        // 4 - Register for the playback finished notification
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];
    }
}
```